# Multiple OneTimeWorkRequest under Worker causing my app to freeze

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I'm trying to refactor app using WorkerManagr and I faced with the following problem.

In several cases in need to call sync on all entities, I do it in the following way:

```
case Constants.Sync.ALL: //MASTER SYNC
                myData = new Data.Builder()
                        .putBoolean(Constants.Sync.FORCE_SYNC, true)
                        .build();
                workRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MasterWorker.class)
                        .setInputData(myData)
                        .build();
                workRequestList.add(workRequest);
                break;
```

And called to enqueue workRequest using:

```
if(workRequestList.size()>0)
            mWorkManagerInstance
                    .enqueue(workRequestList);
```

Which is calling the following class:

```
public class MasterWorker extends Worker {

private Context context;

public MasterWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(context, workerParams);
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    Boolean forceSync = getInputData().getBoolean(Constants.Sync.FORCE_SYNC, true);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MasterService.class);
    i.putExtra(Constants.Sync.FORCE_SYNC, forceSync);
    context.startService(i);
    return Result.SUCCESS;
}
}
```

And from MasterWorker class is called service which is running several services at the same time because these services are not returning a result value.

```
  for (Class s : Constants.ServicesList.services) {
                    if (s.equals(RequestIntentService.class)) {
                        RequestIntentService.startActionMakeRequests(getBaseContext(), Constants.Sync.ALL);
                    }
                    else {
                        Intent i = new Intent(context, s);
                        i.putExtra(Constants.Broadcast.LIST_UPDATE_EVENT, true);
                        i.putExtra(Constants.Broadcast.UPDATE_REMINDERS, false);
                        WorkerHelper.getInstance().startWorkManager(null, i);
                    }
                }
```

Syncing of one, two services works fine. But in this case is need to sync about 8 services, which is causing app freezing.

**Question is:**
How this could be solved in the right way without the need to remove these services, please? Is a possible solution to chain workers in each of them returns `Result.SUCCESS` immediately?

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: What is WorkerHelper doing?
You may trying using [WorkManager beginuniquework](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#beginuniquework) using uniqueWorkName. APPEND as policy. This allows to queue the workers.

Comment: WorkerHelper is singleton holding reference to WorkerManager.